# Passing multiple parameters to apex class from aura component controller read as null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps

From an aura component controller I can pass a single parameter to an apex class just fine, but when I try to pass multiple parameters the first parameter can still be read, but the others are read as null in the debug logs.  I am navigating to this page from a different page and passing params to this page.  I have logged the params in the console and they all have a value.  I have also swapped the value of the truck parameter to myPageRef.state.c__startDate and in the debug logs it has that correct value so I do not think it is a problem with the values being null themselves.

Aura Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" controller="LoadController" >
    <aura:attribute name="messageFromEvent" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.handlePageChange}" />
</aura:component>
```

Aura Component Controller:

```
({
    init: function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
        var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
        console.log(myPageRef.state.c__startDate)
        console.log(myPageRef.state.c__endDate)
        
        var getInitLoads = cmp.get("c.getSpecificLoads");
        getInitLoads.setParams({
            truck: myPageRef.state.c__truck,
            startDate: myPageRef.state.c__startDate,
            endDate: myPageRef.state.c__endDate
        })
        getInitLoads.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('Start debug');
            console.log(state);
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {       
                console.log('This was a success');
            }
        });           
        $A.enqueueAction(getInitLoads);
    },
    
    handlePageChange: function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
        var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
        console.log(myPageRef.state.c__startDate)
        console.log(myPageRef.state.c__endDate)
        
        var getHandleLoads = cmp.get("c.getSpecificLoads");
        getHandleLoads.setParams({
            truck: myPageRef.state.c__truck,
            startDate: myPageRef.state.c__startDate,
            endDate: myPageRef.state.c__endDate
        })
        getHandleLoads.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('Start debug');
            console.log(state);
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {       
                console.log('This was a success');
            }
        });           
        $A.enqueueAction(getHandleLoads);
    }
})
```

LoadController.apxc:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<List<String>> getSpecificLoads(String truck, String startDate, String endDate) {
        System.debug(truck);
        System.debug(startDate);
        System.debug(endDate);
        //Other code and return statement
    }
```

Edit: Small update.  I think it might be some sort of problem with keywords?  I've tried switching the apex class to just take in a string called truck and changed the controller to just pass a single param called truck.  This works fine.  Then I switched the param name to truck2 in both the controller and the apex class.  When I print this out I get null.  I've also tried changing the single param to a bunch of other names, but all of those are printing out null.  Has anyone seen this before?

Edit 2: Alright this is insane.  In my apex class I also have this method:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getFleetId(String trucky) {
        System.debug('We got to the Fleet Id method');
        System.debug(trucky);
        //Other code and return statement
    }
```

In the navigation method for my previous page's controller I have:

```
navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
    var msg = event.getSource().get('v.value');
    var navService = component.find("navService");
    var startDate = component.get("v.startDate");
    var endDate = component.get("v.endDate");
    console.log(msg);
    var action2 = component.get("c.getFleetId");
    console.log(action2);
    action2.setParams({
        trucky: msg
    })
    action2.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('Start debug');
        console.log(state);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log(state)
            var resp = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log(resp);
            var urlArgs = {
                "c__truck": resp,
            }
            if (startDate != null) {
                urlArgs.c__startDate = startDate
            }
            if (endDate != null) {
                urlArgs.c__endDate = endDate
            }
            var pageReference = {
                "type": "standard__component",
                "attributes": {
                    "componentName": "c__Truck_Load_PDF_Viewer"    
                },    
                "state": urlArgs
            };
            component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
            console.log(pageReference);
            var defaultUrl = "#";
            navService.generateUrl(pageReference)
            .then($A.getCallback(function(url) {
                component.set("v.url", url ? url : defaultUrl);
            }), $A.getCallback(function(error) {
                component.set("v.url", defaultUrl);
            }));
            var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");
            event.preventDefault();
            navService.navigate(pageReference);
        }
    });           
    $A.enqueueAction(action2);
 }
```

In the navigate method, if I change the name of the param that I am passing to getFleetId, then all of the variables are now being read correctly in the method in my original question.  However, if I try to change the name of any of those variables from my original question, then they will be read as null.  So I am stuck with that set of params with those names forever unless I change getFleetId's param name.  I do not understand this at all and if someone knows why this would be the case and could explain, then that would be great.  I guess my problem is solved though?

Comment: Share the console logs and debug logs too

Comment: It might not be as helpful as you wish, but once I had a cache problem with Apex as well (it might be your case). It wouldn't read my parameters even though everything was fine. When I changed the name of the function on both Apex and JS Controller it worked, and I decided to keep it this way.

Comment: I had the same problems and i fixed it by clearing the cache